# Debug info slows compiler?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc

I am working on an iPhone app. I compile to two targets, Simulator-debug and Device-Release.

Compiling for simulator is horribly slow but for the device is really fast. The only difference I can see is debug vs release. Does debug info slow things that much?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You're comparing running times between hardware and a software simulator ?

Comment: I comparing compile times targeting hardware and software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't make much of a difference - debug is usually faster to compile because of less optimizations.

Make sure you compare clean build times for each and use the same settings for precompiled headers etc.